# Execute batch file on separate volume - System cannot find the path specified

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, filepath

I have a *batch* file that executes another *batch* file with a couple command line arguments.  This is the command:

```
call "C:/Program Files (x86)/salesforce.com/Data Loader/bin/process.bat", "D:/Scripts/CS Dashboard/DataLoader", "casesByCategory_LM"
```

My problem is that **upon execution, it says "System cannot find the path specified"**.  I realize it is because I am specifying a filepath on a separate drive D:

I tried adding the filepath to the system environment variables but that didn't do any good.

I also tried running this from a command prompt opened from the D: drive which also didn't work.

---

process.bat is a file provided to me by SalesForce to use their DataLoader.  These are the contents:

```
@echo off
if not [%1]==[] goto run
echo.
echo Usage: process ^<configuration directory^> ^[process name^]
echo.
echo      configuration directory -- directory that contains configuration files,
echo          i.e. config.properties, process-conf.xml, database-conf.xml
echo.
echo      process name -- optional name of a batch process bean in process-conf.xml,
echo          for example:
echo.
echo              process ../myconfigdir AccountInsert
echo.
echo          If process name is not specified, the parameter values from config.properties
echo          will be used to run the process instead of process-conf.xml,
echo          for example:
echo.
echo              process ../myconfigdir
echo.

goto end

:run
set PROCESS_OPTION=
if not [%2]==[] set PROCESS_OPTION=process.name=%2

..\Java\bin\java.exe -cp ..\dataloader-29.0.0-uber.jar -Dsalesforce.config.dir=%1 com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner %PROCESS_OPTION%

:end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the commas and use backslash as path separator.

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin\process.bat" "D:\Scripts\CS Dashboard\DataLoader" casesByCategory_LM
```

If this does not work then you should post your `process.bat` code

Comment: Hmm, I tried that and it's still giving me the same error

Comment: @RyanMcClure, then, assuming the file is in the indicated path, the problem is probably inside `process.bat`

Comment: @RyanMcClure, the code in the `process.bat` file uses relative paths to access the needed files. If the *current folder* is not what it needs to be, the files will not be found. Maybe a `cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\bin"` before the `call` will make it work